# iPhone to iPhone Data Transfer using NFC

Tags: android, ios, swift, nfc, transfer

I am currently making an app where certain data (text and maybe an image) is transferred from one phone to another (`iOS` or `Android`). I want to use something like `NFC` to transfer this data, so that two users can just tap their phones and transfer data.

Is this possible?

If so, any useful links or guides?

Thanks

Comment: An app on an iOS device cannot "write" NFC data, it can only read NDEF tags

Comment: @Paulw11, what about this ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/creating_nfc_tags_from_your_iphone ?

Comment: @Paulw11, whatever, any idea how to transfer photo/file for iphone to iphone which support nfc read/write ? And what about NFC image/file sharing iPhone to Android or vice-versa  ? I meant, i want to communicate with other phone(contains NFC) only, no external NFC tag/reader. My intension is work with no connection hassle. Please, suggest me the best option. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Core NFC allows an iPhone to read and write supported NFC tag types, but it doesn't enable an iPhone to act as an NFC tag, so it isn't suitable for communication between two iOS devices

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive about NFC support for iOS, but they do supper Nearby messages between both platforms. https://developers.google.com/nearby/overview

Comment: Interesting, this just might be the solution to my 'issue'. I will look into it and mark your answer as being the solution if it is. Thanks!